# Asking for changing the air flow (straighten or tilt)

Tags: word-usage

In a car, we can change the direction of the air flow. If the flow of the air is in the direction of the person and the person starts feeling cold, and wants the direction of the air flow to be changed,  what will be a natural way to describe that?

> Can you please tilt the air flow?
>
> Can you straighten the air flow?

(Depending on where you're sitting)

And if someone is feeling hot and wants the flow of air to be in his direction, what will be a natural way to describe it?

> Can you please straighten the air flow? 
>   (If you're sitting straighten direction of  the air flow)
>
> Can you please tilt the air flow?
>   (If you're sitting in diagonal direction to the air flow?

Or simply:

> Can you turn the air flow in my direction?

Do all of the sentences above sound natural?

Comment: Every one of those sentences sounds unnatural to me. They are grammatical, but not something I would ever expect anybody to say. In particular, nobody would talk about *air flow* in normal conversation in that context. They would simply say something like *Could you turn the air away from me?* Assuming they even had to ask. Normally, they would simply reach out and adjust it themselves. (So the conversation would never happen in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

In a car, the way I typically say these things would be:

> Can you **point** the air away from me?
>
> or
>
> Can you **point** the air at/toward me?

"air flow" is too technical of a word to describe this, and makes it sound like you are talking about aerodynamics. Using "the air" or "the AC" is more appropriate.

Because then you are not talking about the flow of the air, but rather the air conditioning as a concept, it makes more sense to "point" as opposed to "tilt" or "straighten". "Turn" could be used here as well instead of "point"